# Why are multiplications by constant signed integer fractions not optimised?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-optimization

Since signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour I expected the three functions below to compile to the same or similar assembly. This is however not the case. `test2` is slightly different from `test1` and `test3` uses two `imul` instructions that are not required for the other examples.

```
int test1(int x)
{
    return x * 5 / 2;
}

int test2(int x)
{
    return x * 10 / 4;
}

int test3(int x)
{
    return x * 50 / 20;
}
```

[comparison on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/hDQqaC)

Is there a reason why compilers don't perform this kind of optimizaion?

Comment: See ex. `printf("%d %d\n", test1(INT_MAX), test3(INT_MAX));`

Comment: I don't think there is anything in the formal C++ spec itself that prevents this kind of an optimization. I think it's as simple as "it hasn't occured to anyone before", that one can try to micro-optimize an integer multiplication followed by division to find some mathematically-identical sequence whose multiplication and division step can be done by optimized machine language instructions.

Comment: @KamilCuk in my opinion the compiler should still be able to cancel the larger fractions. Just like in this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/8F-ZyW) where the compiler makes a similar optimization when both numerator and denominator are powers of two.

Comment: `are powers of two` Not neceserraly. It happens when having `x * a / b` and `a` is divisble by `b`. Then it's trasformed into `x * (a/b)`. Compare ex. `x * 1000 / 50`

Comment: The optimisation you expect *is* performed if the two factors cancel out to an integer value. I'm not sure whether the rounding division could behave differently or if the compiler just cannot prove that it doesn't.

Comment: I would have thought that `test3()` could be validly optimised to be the same as `test1()`.

Comment: I suspect this is related to GCC supporting wrapping for signed integer overflow. This is not required by the C standard but is mentioned in the GCC documentation. `x * 5 / 2`, `x * 10 / 4`, and `x * 50 / 20` produce different results in the presence of overflow, so they cannot be optimized to the same code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil IINM that's only with `-frapv`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I would have thought that an optimisation that reduces the risk overflow *in the intermediate step* is a good thing.

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, I tested compiling with `-fwrapv` and `-fnowrapv` to see if this affected the code. It does not, but the documentation for `-fwrapv` only says it instructs the compiler to “assume” that signed arithmetic wraps (e.g., it tells the compiler that is what the machine instructions do?). It does not tell us that it changes what GCC attempts to provide for signed arithmetic overflow.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's not necessarily about avoiding overflow. If GCC has well-defined signed overflow, then it would have to ensure that it always behaves as if that overflow did occur.

Comment: Interesting to include `return x * 2 + x/2;` as that has the widest range of `x` before UB kicks in.

Comment: Patch welcome. Optimizations are only done in compilers because someone motivated implemented them.

Answer (score 1):

Whether such an optimization would be correct would depend upon what if anything an implementation guarantees about the effects of integer overflow:

1. If an implementation guarantees that integer additions and multiplications will always behave as though performed with values large enough to hold the result and then two's-complement truncated to the type's size after each operation, replacement of `x*(m*a)/(m*b)` with `x*a/b` would violate such guarantees.
2. If an implementation guarantees that integer addition and multiplication will always behave as though they yield some number, but does not guarantee that temporary values will be truncated to any particular size, such an optimization would be valid.
3. If an implementation guarantees nothing about the effects of overflow, and requires that programmers avoid them at all costs, because they may cause erroneous behavior even in parts of the program that don't use the result, such an optimization would be valid.

The gcc compiler offers options to either uphold the strong guarantee option #1, or refrain from offering any guarantees whatsoever, and the possibility of integer overflows disrupting parts of the code which don't use the result isn't merely theoretical.  Because option #3 would be recklessly dangerous for programs that would receive input from potentially untrustworthy sources, and because gcc doesn't offer any settings between #1 and #3, many programs, including those where option #2 would have met requirements, are built with the `fwrapv` flag which forces option #1.